# How to open particular fragment on the click of the push notification message?

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

I want to open the particular fragment on the click of the push notification message.In my case fragment is open when the notification occurs.but i want to open the fragment on the click of the notification message instead of arriving the message.

This is my sendNotification() method :-

```
 private void sendNotification(String msg) {

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("data", "fromoutside");
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);


        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                .setContentTitle("Telepoh")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);


        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

This is my onNewIntent() method which override in the MainActivity where i open the fragment :-

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Fragment fragment = new NotificationActivity();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    }
```

My Problem is I want to open this fragment on the click of the push notification message but in my case the fragment is open when the push notification message is arrive.

Comment: Add an action to the intent (be sure to make it unique) in `sendNotification()` method. And then in `onNewIntent()` get Action and only open the fragment if/when the correct intent arrives.

Comment: I tried this method but it does not work ! can you please write  some code if i done any mistake.

Comment: Add your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Please Check the Updated Code. in my main activity i added android:launchMode="singleTop".

Comment: Just wondering, why do you want to create a new fragment when it is already open? I think I might be misunderstanding the problem

Comment: @Zach the problem is when the push notification message is arrive.then the it opens the notification fragment.but i want when i click on the notification message in the notification tab after that it opens. instead of arrives the notification.

Comment: @LoveAndroid oh i see. I added an answer, hopefully this solves your problem

Answer (score 6):

I found the mistake and solved it on my own way :-

change the flags in sendNotification() method like this :-

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("data", "fromoutside");


        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

and in MainActivity change the code in override method onNewIntent() as like this :-

```
 @Override
            protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
                super.onNewIntent(intent);

                if (intent != null) {

                    String data = intent.getStringExtra("data");

                    if (data != null) {

                        Fragment fragment = new NotificationActivity();
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

                    } 


                }


        }
```

Happy Coding :))

Answer (score 0):

These lines of code right here are starting a new activity immediately since they are outside of a listener or some other condition.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra("data", "fromoutside");
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

From what I see, you just need to remove the 4 lines above.

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
...
mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```

These lines should be enough to get your notification to start the intent when clicked.

For reference: [the developer guide for notifications](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html)